# Capturing who has updated my dynamodb records in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a AWS dynamodb. How to know who has updated the records in my table (not the table)? Need to know the details like logged-in user id or ARN of the AWS services which has updated the records in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Updated: 8.16.2021
Cloudtrail now suppoerst tracking data events for DynamoDB
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/03/aws-cloudtrail-adds-logging-of-data-events-for-amazon-dynamoDB/

DynamoDB does not let you inquire which user last modified a certain item. Nor does log these data modification events anywhere. The [DynamoDB Detective Security Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices-security-detective.html) explains your options:

- If all you want to log are administrative operations, such as table creation and deletion, then [AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html) is good enough for you. This feature gives you a log of all these administrative operations, and which user did which.
- However, you said that you want to know about data-plane operations (PutItem, UpdateItem, etc.), not just control-plane operations. So CloudTrail is not good enough for you. The remaining option is to use DynamoDB Streams. This creates a "stream" of modification events to your database, where each event also records the user who did this modification. A dedicated application can listen to this stream, and either record the information of who-modified-what, or react to suspicious activity, or whatever you want to do with it.

Using Streams as suggested above is neither easy nor free to do. But without doing this, the information of which user modifies which item is simply not recorded anywhere by DynamoDB.

Answer (score -1):

This is where CloudTrail would come in handy. CloudTrail can be attached to services, including DynamoDB, so you can see any operations on your tables.

Here is a tutorial for it:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html

Comment: I don't think CloudTrail actually does what SG asked for. According to the documentation you linked to, it keeps track of administrative operations like creating a table, but not of data operations - PutItem, UpdateItem, and so on. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices-security-detective.html says: "AWS CloudTrail does not support logging of DynamoDB data-plane operations, such as PutItem. So you might want to consider using Amazon DynamoDB Streams as a source for these events occurring in your environment."